What is the procedure to expense qualified medical equipment on an FSA?
If I want to buy a ergonomic chair (the one I'm looking at is $1,600) can I do so and expense it on my FSA? If so what is the procedure to do this?

The procedure is as follows,

Make a purchase for a qualified item. The full list of qualified expenses is on the IRS's site. Some examples include (source fsafeds.gov). If you have any doubt if your doctor is on board, get the letter below first.

Allergy treatments products (HEPA filters, Air purifier, etc.)
Cosmetic procedures or surgery (for birth defects, accidents, and/or disease)
Home medical equipment (such as reclining chairs, special mattress, humidifier, vaporizer)
Health club dues (as treatment for a medical condition diagnosed by a licensed health care professional)
Supplements (for treatment of medical condition)
Weight loss program (for treatment of a medical condition), not including cost of food
Wigs for hair loss due to chemotherapy or radiation treatment


Fill out a Letter of Medical Necessity, it must have the following information (from fsafeds.gov). You can find an example of the letter here. Your FSA provider may have it's own variant under a different name, mine calls it a "Certification of Medical Necessity"

Patient name
Participant name
Participant employer
Last 4 digits of Social Security Number
Medical condition
Describe recommended treatment (frequency and dosage)
Duration of the treatment
Provider's name
Provider's signature
Date


Submit Letter of Medical Necessity with your receipt to FSA provider.



I would argue you should get your doctor to fill out the LMN before purchasing the item. Just so you know your doctor is on board before you spend any money.

@Nosjack updated with that note.

If it is an approved medical expense,  then the details of submitting the expense depend on your FSA administrator. Ask them. For mine, I could either use a debit card associated with the FSA, or pay out of pocket and submit the receipt for reimbursement.
According to a websearch, the IRS defines qualified medical expenses as amounts paid for the “diagnosis, cure, mitigation, treatment, or prevention of disease, or for the purpose of affecting any structure or function of the body.” Qualified medical expenses are eligible for reimbursement through your FSA as long as they are not reimbursed. Some ergonomic adaptations certainly ought to qualify, as preventing / managing RSI and similar ailments, but whether a specific expensive chair is covered may depend on whether you can get your doctor to write a prescription for it.
Good luck. Personally, my plan is to take the cheap way out and buy a basic gamer's chair, commonly available for a quarter of that price and certainly good enough for my needs. It may or may not qualify for reimbursement, but with the lower price I don't care as much.

I'm looking at the Herman Miller Logitech Gaming Chair, it's $1600 at 20% off. =/ But I think it would be easy to get a doctor's note. I don't know that it's a "prescription" as you call it. I think there is a name and format for the letter, which would make a great extension to your answer.

If you can find the proper term I'd be glad to add it in. Herman Miller is at the high end of the price range; I'd spend some time testing others to decide if it justifies that cost. Medical spending should be driven by benefit, not prestige.

Called a Letter of Medical Necessity https://www.fsafeds.gov/public/pdf/FSAFEDS-Letter-of-Medical-Necessity-Form%20FINAL-es.pdf?h=dxieh89utd5zujtabfmqbzfjcoii5u9r5b61omyj8g75bghcxkoo There is the form. Guess you just fill it out and have a doctor sign it. I think Herman Miller is quality -- with that always comes prestige. They make chairs with a 12 year warranty and a history for lasting. $1,600 / 12 years, is $133/yr that hardly seems unreasonable when you're working from home.

@EvanCarroll the medical necessity may be for an ergonomic chair, but not for a 12-year warranty. FSA administrators are not in the business of being reasonable.
